# API Authentication using Node and Google OAuth2 (googleapis). Recommended way of authenticating the user?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, google-oauth

I'm little confussed on how to handle user authorization for secured routes using the Google OAuth2 for the API authentication. I'd be glad for some guidance.

**Overview:**

My API acts on behalf of the user to access Google services. I'm requesting the "offline" access_type to retrieve the refresh token. I using the oAuth2Client from `googleapis` library.

My authentication flow is following:

1. (Client) Requests auth url from the API. The API function:

```
    getAuthUrl() {
      try {
        const scopes = [
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
          'openid',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly',
        ];

        const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
          access_type: 'offline',
          scope: scopes,
          include_granted_scopes: true,
          prompt: 'consent',
        });

        return authUrl;
      } catch (e) {
        throw new AuthServiceError((e as Error)?.message);
      }
    }
```

2. (Client) redirects to the auth url received from the API. Receives `authorizationCode` and requests API for the tokens. The API function:

```
    async getTokens(authorizationCode: string) {
      try {
        const { tokens } = await oAuth2Client.getToken(authorizationCode);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

        const { credentials } = oAuth2Client;
        const idToken = credentials.id_token;
        const refreshToken = credentials.refresh_token;

        if (!idToken) {
          throw new Error(ErrorMessage.TOKENS_MISSING_ID_TOKEN);
        }
        if (!refreshToken) {
          throw new Error(ErrorMessage.TOKENS_MISSING_REFRESH_TOKEN);
        }

        return {
          idToken,
          refreshToken,
        };
      } catch (e) {
        throw new AuthServiceError((e as Error)?.message);
      }
    },
```

3. In the API controller that calls (2) `getTokens`, I retrieve the user's info with received tokens using `google.oauth2.userinfo.get`. Then, I call the DB to create a user, based on received userInfo (if user does not exist), and return the JWT - `idToken` (retrieved from (2) `getTokens`). Controller code:

```
    async googleTokens(req, res, next) {
      try {
        const { authorizationCode } = req.body;

        const { idToken, refreshToken } =
          await googleAuthService.getTokens(authorizationCode);

        const { userId } = await googleAuthService.getUserInfo(refreshToken);

        // In the database, find or create user with given userId, then, return userData.
        const userData = await db.user.findOrCreate(userId);

          res.send({
            data: {
              user: {
                ...userData,
                idToken,
              },
            },
          });
      } catch (e) {
        next(e);
      }
    },
```

4. (Client) To access secured content, in request to the API user sets `Authorization` header with value set to `Bearer <idToken>`. The ID token is stored on the client (for simplicity, let's skip the security behind that).
5. (Server) For secured routes, a middleware checks if the `idToken` received in the request's header is valid (using `verifyIdToken` from the googleapis `google.oauth.OAuth2` library). And allows to enter the route.

**Questions:**

1. The JWT `idToken` received in the exchange for the `authorizationCode` in step (2) expires after 1 hour. What's the recommended way of refreshing it? Should it be handled on the server-side or client-side?
2. Is this strategy valid for correctly implementing the API authentication using Google OAuth2? If not, how should I approach the authentication considering I want to:

- Act on behalf of the user to access Google services (offline)
- Create a user account in the database, and authorize the API requests for secured content

Comment: I'd token is authentication.    Refresh token and access token are authorization.     Use the refresh token to get a new access token to access YouTube on behalf of the user

Comment: You’re right. Accessing the Youtube API is clear for me. I store the refresh token in the database, and use it to generate a valid access token.

Comment: I’m not sure how to handle the flow of authenticating the user on the server side - I’m expecting the IdToken in the Authorization header, but how should I refresh it given my existing strategy (see step (5))?

Comment: I'd token will only come when the user is there to authenticate or sign in.    You don't refresh an id token